# Magento 2 error - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'trim' of undefined

Tags: magento2, product, checkout, onepage-checkout, place-order

Error while clicking on **place order** button, how to trace this error (in which file ),

in order to fix it - `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'trim' of undefined`

Comment: Did you found any solution on this?

Comment: Yes , its because var was undefined and trim method was attached to it.

Comment: you can add the answer to your own question (what you did to resolve) so if someone faces this issue so your answer can help.

Comment: Yup great idea , thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variable was undefined , that is why trim method was throwing error.